# Why I sometimes see "INIT: version 2.88 reloading" in the console?

Tags: linux, debian, sysvinit

As far as I understand, the init should automatically restart when I update the package with init or some dependency like libc6.

Why I see `INIT: version 2.88 reloading` in console without having installed recently anything that important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably caused by `prelink` being run every day:

```
# grep init /etc/cron.*/*
/etc/cron.daily/prelink:    # Restart init if needed
/etc/cron.daily/prelink:    [ -n "$(find `ldd /sbin/init | awk 'NF == 4 { print $3 }'` /sbin/init -ctime -1 2>/dev/null )" ] && /sbin/telinit u
...
```